# react modal image doesn't show large size image when being clicked

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, react-modal

I have code below to display images in `Image.Group` with size prop to be set to "small". In side the `Image.Group`, I used `ModalImage` which is imported from `react-modal-image`. It is supposed to display large size photo when the image is clicked. But the fact is that when the image is clicked, it still shows the same size image as before. I know the problem is from `size="small"`, and ModalImage simply inherits the prop from Image.Group. In this case, how can I overwrite the size to large in case the image is clicked?

```
<Image.Group size="small">
  {photos &&
    photos.map(photo => (
      <LazyLoad key={photo.name} height={150}>
        <ModalImage
          small={photo.url}
          large={photo.url}
          alt={photo.name}
          hideDownload={true}
          hideZoom={true}
        />;
      </LazyLoad>
    ))}
</Image.Group>
```

Before being clicked:[image]
After being clicked:[image]

Comment: Might be the actual size of image is this only. Can you provide the actual image and link for `ModalImage` library?

Comment: There you go: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/freebies-df71a.appspot.com/o/rJvrYSQku3TrLWfNB673%2Fphotos%2Fimage.jpg?alt=media&token=fda54bde-9577-45f4-9631-9aa0ebf3da35

Comment: The image shown in post is horizontally displayed, try to rotate it to get the vertical image.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't help, still the small size

Comment: What is `ModalImage`? Any external package? Or can you provide codepen for this?

Comment: The thing is if I removed size="small" in Image.Group, I can see the large image when clicking the image, but the image before being clicked is no longer a small-sized thumbnail, it is also big size.

Comment: @ravibagul91ModalImage is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-image. Sorry I don't know how to setup codepen :(

Comment: I also don't know what is happening, I tried with simple image and it is working fine. I doubt it is due to `height={150}` on `Lazyload` component. Whta is it? Try to remove it and check if you are getting same result.

Comment: Hi damingzi, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is due to `height={150}` on `Lazyload` component.

if you want to show your image thumbnail of size `150px`, then you can add a class name on `ModalImage` and apply `CSS` to that class name.

```
<LazyLoad key={photo.name}>  //Remove height here
   <ModalImage
      small={photo.url}
      large={photo.url}
      alt={photo.name}
      hideDownload={true}
      hideZoom={true}
      className="modal-image"    //Add a class name here
   />;
</LazyLoad>
```

Apply `CSS` to `modal-image` class,

```
.modal-image{
  max-height: 150px !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fc3kpr)

Comment: Thanks Ravi!. You give me a clue on using className. The real problem is in size="small". After removing size="small", and define a customized className for small image display, the problem is solved. Thanks again!